# UITextField bug while animating

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uianimation

I have UITextField and UIView animation which show and hide container with text field. If I edit text and then hide my text field, i see that text immediately change a frame at zero position, and then animate at normal place.

But it happens only at first hiding and only if some text inputed. I'll be grateful for any ideas!

[image]

There is show\hide action code:

```
- (IBAction)showOrHideSearchBar:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected) {
        self.searchBarTopConstraint.constant = self.searchBarContainerView.frame.size.height;
        [self.searchTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        self.searchBarTopConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.searchTextField endEditing:YES];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:SEARCH_BAR_ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
        [self.searchBarContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: If you want to animate u r textfield when text added or its selected, why can't you add your animation code into your if (sender.selected) block

Comment: I want to show or hide container with textfield from navigation bar when button selected, no matter is there text or not. Anyway replacing code of animation have no effect